# Unable to write to a folder on a drive on AiX system

Tags: permissions, aix, touch, read-write

I logged in the server with the below user id.

```
myhost:hkgdb:/wd/user1>id
uid=214(user1) gid=321(dba) groups=1(staff)
```

I'm getting the following error while writing to a file:

```
myhost:hkgdb:/wd/user1>touch /backup/myhost/test.touch
touch: 0652-046 Cannot create /backup/myhost/test.touch.
```

I see that I have good permissions on the folder.

```
myhost:hkgdb:/wd/user1>ls -ld /backup
drwxrwxrwx  841 root     system        31449 May 09 10:25 /backup

myhost:hkgdb:/wd/user1>ls -ld /backup/myhost
drwxr-xr-x    2 user1   dba            3221 Jan 06 2019  /backup/myhost
```

My operating system details are below:

```
myhost:hkgdb:/backup/myhost>uname -a
AIX myhost 1 7 000D1F9BD400
```

Below are the details of the backup drive.

```
df -gt | grep backup
10.9.90.107:/ifs/data/NAS_BKP 396149.93 384419.14  11730.80   98% /backup
```

Can you please suggest what could be the issue and how can I resolve it ?

Comment: You have NFS mounted that directory from somewhere. What user does UID correspond to on the NFS server and does that user access to write in that directory? I'm thinking it has to do with https://serverfault.com/questions/591143/nfsv4-permissions-on-aix

Comment: It doesn't say it is a permission-problem. For example it might be read-only or out-of-inodes.